# Is it safe to pass undefined in React's onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it safe to pass `undefined` in React's `onClick` handler?

I just tried and everything still works, but I can't find any line about that in docs.

Example:

```
function MonthBar(props) {
  /* is it okay when props.onClick === undefined ? */
  return <span onClick={props.onClick}>{props.monthName}</span>;
}

MonthBar.propType = {
  onClick:  React.PropTypes.func, // optional                   
  monthName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to pass in `undefined` as the `onClick` handler. They already have to handle that case implicitly since it's an optional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

passing `undefined` can be handled by checking it on your `onClick`,

```
function MonthBar(props) {
/* is it okay when props.onClick === undefined ? */
  return (
   <span onClick={props.onClick !== undefined? props.onClick : ''}>
    {props.monthName}
   </span>);
}

MonthBar.propType = {
  onClick:  React.PropTypes.func, // optional                   
  monthName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

the concern should be more about you want to pass the `undefined` to the onClick or not

Comment: BTW, checking `undefined` with `=== undefined` is not good idea. `typeof props.onClick !== 'undefined'` should be much robust.P.S. but this is not what I was asking for.