# using onClick with array map in Dynamic menu ( ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a dynamic menu from an array but I only want an onClick method on the last item.This is in a ReactJS component. In the dropDownMenu.map, how do I setup the anchor tag to only have an onClick as defined in the array?

```
const dropDownMenu = [
    { name: 'Profile', href: '#' },
    { name: 'Settings', href: '#' },
    { name: 'Sign out', href: '#', onClick=logOut }
];

const logout = () => {
  signOut();
};

{dropDownMenu.map((item) => (
  <Menu.Item key={item.name}>
    {({ active }) => (
        <a href={item.href}>
          {item.name}
        </a>
    )}
  </Menu.Item>
))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to check anything in onClick it's an extra useless code react handle this implicitly if the clickHandler is undefined. this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194122/is-it-safe-to-pass-undefined-in-reacts-onclick) may help you.

```
const logout = () => {
  signOut();
};

const dropDownMenu = [
  { name: "Profile", href: "#" },
  { name: "Settings", href: "#" },
  { name: "Sign out", href: "#", clickHandler: logOut },
];

{
  dropDownMenu.map((item) => (
    <Menu.Item key={item.name}>
      {({ active }) => <a onClick={item.clickHandler} href={item.href}>{item.name}</a>}
    </Menu.Item>
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.map has a second parameter in it's callback function, you can check to see if it is the last value in the array, and if it is, you can pass the callback

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
const dropDownMenu = [
    { name: 'Profile', href: '#' },
    { name: 'Settings', href: '#' },
    { name: 'Sign out', href: '#' }
];

const logout = () => {
    signOut();
};

{
    dropDownMenu.map((item, index) => (
        <Menu.Item key={item.name}>
            {({ active }) => (
                <a href={item.href} onClick={dropDownMenu.length - 1 === index ? logout : null}>
                    {item.name}
                </a>
            )}
        </Menu.Item>
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onClick and href props are available in an anchor tag, you can directly pass using destructuring.

```
const dropDownMenu = [
    { name: 'Profile', href: '#' },
    { name: 'Settings', href: '#' },
    { name: 'Sign out', href: '#', onClick:logOut }
];

const logout = () => {
  signOut();
};

{dropDownMenu.map(({name, ...rest}) => (
  <Menu.Item key={name}>{({ active }) => (<a {...rest}>{name}</a>)}</Menu.Item>
))}
```